# Не запускается самый простой GUI проект!

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt

Установил на Ubuntu Qt, решил запустить один из проектов-примеров, а он на тебе:

> **20:45:37: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
>   g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/urik/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/urik/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -o qmlvideofx filereader.o main.o frequencymonitor.o frequencymonitordeclarative.o performancemonitor.o performancemonitordeclarative.o qrc_qmlvideofx.o qrc_frequencymonitordeclarative.o qrc_performancemonitordeclarative.o moc_filereader.o moc_frequencymonitor.o   -L/home/urik/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Gui -lQt5Qml -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
>
> Makefile:245: recipe for target 'qmlvideofx' failed collect2: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [qmlvideofx] Error 1
20:45:37: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта qmlvideofx (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 GCC 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»**

Вечный вопрос - что не так?

Comment: Русским по белому написано: не может найти GL. libGL попробуйте поставить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, спасибо за разъяснение ошибки, а какой пакет лучше - libgl1-mesa-dev пойдет?

Comment: Все, спасибо, после установки библиотеки, которую я указал выше, все заработало!

Comment: Попробуй code block с компилем, эта прога и на калькуляторах потянет)

Answer (score 4):

Раз помогло: нужно установить libGL